# Loops - Will not start over, just spams out a string

Tags: python, loops, python-3.3

So I'm trying to get loops to work with a program (credits to Codeacademy for PygLatin). 
I've tried with various "break" and other syntax's with no success. What I want the loop to do is to start over, from the input (line 4). As of now I manage to stop the loop with `PygLatin = False`, but not start over again. As you see on the last line I write `PygLatin = True`, but that only spams out `"Not a string"`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
pyg = 'ay'

print("Welcome to PygLatin!")
original = input('Enter a word: ')      #Asks user to enter a word

PygLatin = True
while PygLatin:
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():    
        word = original.lower()                     
        first = word[0]                         

        if first in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:   
            new_word = word + pyg               
            print(new_word)
            PygLatin = False
        else:                    
            new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + pyg     
            print(new_word)
            PygLatin = False                                           
    else:
        print('Error: Not a string!')                
        PygLatin = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the `input`, too:

```
while True:
    original = input(...)
    PygLatin = True
    while PygLatin:
        if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
            ...
        else:
            print('Error: Not a string!')
    ui = input("Try again? (y/n): ").lower()
    if ui not in ("y", "yes"):
        break
```

This will ask the user each time if they want to loop again.